# Помогите решить проблему с счётчиком лайков

Tags: javascript, html, css, counter

Кто-то может понять в чем причина, счётчик лайков не работает, но в консоли нормально все показывает

```js
const input = document.querySelector('.input')
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn')
const test = document.querySelector('.test')
let counter = document.querySelector('.counter')

const addPost = () => {
  counter = 0;
  const markup = 
  `<div class="test-wrapper">
      <div class="test-message">
         <img src="img/images.png" alt="">
         <h3 class="message-text">${input.value}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="test-like">
         <svg height="20px" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="20px" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
          <g id="_x31_66_x2C__Heart_x2C__Love_x2C__Like_x2C__Twitter">
       <g>
                <path d="M365.4,59.628c60.56,0,109.6,49.03,109.6,109.47c0,109.47-109.6,171.8-219.06,281.271    C146.47,340.898,37,278.568,37,169.099c0-60.44,49.04-109.47,109.47-109.47c54.73,0,82.1,27.37,109.47,82.1    C283.3,86.999,310.67,59.628,365.4,59.628z";/>
       </g>
            </g>
            <g id="Layer_1"/>
         </svg>
         <p class="counter">${counter}</p>
        </div>
     </div>`

  test.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', markup)
  const like = document.querySelector('svg')

  like.addEventListener('click', () => {
    addCounter()
  })

  const addCounter = () => {
    counter += 1;
    console.log(counter)
  }
}
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  addPost();
})
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@700&family=Tiro+Tamil&display=swap");
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.test-wrapper {
  height: 75px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.test-message img {
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
}

.message-text {
  display: inline-block;
}

svg {
  fill: #eee;
}

svg:hover {
  fill: red;
}

.counter {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="img/favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="test">

    </div>

    <input class="input" type="text" name="message">
    <button class="btn">click</button>
  </div>

  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В чём была твоя ошибка, ты пытаешься привязать к псевдо-элементу.

А надо было привязаться к parent, ибо тот-же клик передаться от всех наследников к единому контейнеру.

```
messagesContainer.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  const like = event.target.closest(".test-like"); // Выбираем ближайший .test-like из parents
  if (like === null) return; // Если такового нету, значаит клик был не на лайк
  const counter = like.querySelector("P.counter"); // Выбираем ближайший children P.counter
  if (counter !== null) { // Если нету, значит херня какая-то
    counter.dataset.count = parseInt(counter.dataset.count) + 1; // Увеличиваем на 1
    counter.textContent = counter.dataset.count; // Выводим значение
  }
});
```

Вот рабочий вариант твоего счётчика.

- https://codepen.io/latdev/pen/LYQdwZg

Comment: ps: А ещё дико бесят конструкции `const addPost = () => {}` Вот скажи чем тебе `function addPost() {}` не угодил? Тебе что надо передавать где-то this в функцию? Если ты не относишь код к классу то вообще зачем так писать? Это становиться жутко нечитаемо, аш противно.

Comment: Прости, не бей пожалуйста, я в основном так и пишу function и так далее, это просто единичный случай такой

Comment: @АндрейХотюн Ну надеюсь ) Просто shorthands делают код совершенно нечитаемым, честно.

Comment: А если допустим надо убрать лайки, тоесть поставил лайк, передумал и еще раз нажал и убрал, это через условного оператора делать, да? Прописать в likeContainer.addEventListener?